# JS redirect issue

Tags: javascript, php, html, apache

I have 3 files and I want the users to be able to choose which to download from a drop down list. All is OK with the below piece of code, except if I choose the first "option" `Please select` it goes up a level. So the page I have is `http:\\mydomain\mysite\subfolder1\subfolder2\download.htm` and if I click on `Please select` it redirects(?) the browser to `http:\\mydomain\mysite\subfolder1\subfolder2\` where there is no index so it lists the files in that folder. I just want nothing to happen if I click on that one.

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function download(d) {
        if (d != 'Please select')
        {
        window.location = d; }
}
</script>

<select name="download" onChange="download(this.value)">
<option>Please select</option>
<option value="link">1</option>
<option value="link">2</option>
<option value="link">3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Please select` has no value,

try like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function download(d) {
        if (d)
        {
             window.location = d; 
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If there's not `value` present in selected `option`, the [option text is used](http://jsfiddle.net/gjyz2y5y/) instead as the value of the `select` element. Hence OP's code should work as it is.

Comment: @Pascalz Thanks a lot. Will be able to accept as a solution soon.